# Changing the definitions of outline-minor-mode headings

Tags: hooks, minor-mode, outline-mode, outline

I would like to change the pattern for heading in `outline-minor-mode`.  Have came up with the following implementation for `emacs-lisp-mode` that uses a minor-mode called `taxocask-minor-mode`.

```
(defvar taxocask-elisp-hglevels
  '( (";; H1" . 1) (";; H2" . 2) (";; H3" . 3) (";; H4" . 4)
     (";; H5" . 5) (";; H6" . 6) (";; H7" . 7) (";; H8" . 8) )

  "Set outline levels for for command shell outline headings.")

(defvar taxocask-elisp-mglevels
  '( (";; M1" . 1) (";; M2" . 2) (";; M3" . 3) (";; M4" . 4)
     (";; M5" . 5) (";; M6" . 6) (";; M7" . 7) (";; M8" . 8) )

  "Set outline levels for in Marginalia and levels for command
shell marginal headings.")

(defvar taxocask-elisp-hklevels
  (append taxocask-elisp-hglevels
          taxocask-elisp-mglevels)
  "Set the hierarchical levels for outlines in elisp Major-Mode.")

(defun taxocask-elisp-headings ()
  "Sets elisp headings for outline mode."
  (interactive)

  (let ( (hklevels taxocask-elisp-hklevels) )

    (setq outline-regexp
           (concat (regexp-opt (mapcar 'car hklevels)) "\\>"))
    (setq outline-heading-alist hklevels)) )

(defun taxocask-elisp-addhooks ()
   "Sets the headings function to the elisp hook."

   (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'taxocask-elisp-headings))
```

How can I activate these tools in the minor-mode.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to invoke those functions when you turn on the minor mode? If so then use the minor mode's hook, e.g., `outline-minor-mode-hook`.

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  "..."
  (taxocask-elisp-headings)
  (taxocask-elisp-addhooks))

(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'foo)
```

Comment: Yes I want to see how the functions should be invoked.

Comment: What does that mean? I showed you how to invoke them.

Comment: `taxocask-elisp-addhooks` already hooks `taxocask-elisp-headings`.

Comment: @konmi: So? If it hurts then don't do that...